# Rendering HTML+CSS Content with html2canvas and jsPDF not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to use the html2canvas scripts to render my webpage with css and save it to PDF. But nothing gets triggered on clicking the link to download as pdf. Here is my code :-

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor"></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function genPDF()
            {
                html2canvas(document.body, {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {

                        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        var doc = new jsPDF();
                        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
                        doc.save('test.pdf');
                    }

                });

            }
        </script>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

            <p>a pararaph</p>

        </div>
        <a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: The code is running fine with jsfiddle.. I don't know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: If it works in a fiddle then you most likely have missed a script include or a document.ready handler. I'm sure there will be an error in that case. To open the console press F12 in your browser. Errors will be in red in the lower pane

Comment: I know Java and working with javascript and jquery for the first time. Could you guys help me by rectifying my code may be?

Comment: The console error points to the html2canvas file. Am I using the right scripts?

Comment: Solved!! There was problem in the imported script.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'd suggest deleting this question now, as it's unlikely to help any future visitors as it was a configuration problem.